# Using MySQL Pivot Table Queries for a Monthly Attendance Report

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have used pivot query for monthly report..

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
  `empID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `deptID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attStatus` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empID`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For monthly attendance report, I have used this query:

```
SELECT empID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 1, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day1', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 2, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day2', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 3, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day3', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 4, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day4', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 5, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day5', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 6, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day6', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 7, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day7', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 8, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day8', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 9, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day9', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 10, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day10',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 11, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day11', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 12, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day12', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 13, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day13', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 14, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day14', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 15, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day15', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 16, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day16', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 17, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day17', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 18, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day18', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 19, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day19', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 20, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day20', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 21, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day21', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 22, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day22', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 23, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day23', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 24, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day24', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 25, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day25', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 26, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day26', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 27, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day27', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 28, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day28', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 29, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day29', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 30, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day30',  
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`date`) = 31, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'day31', 
  COUNT(if(`attStatus`='P', `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'totalP'
FROM `attendance`
WHERE deptID=1 AND `date` BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31'
GROUP BY empID
```

So my question is, isn't this query too long?
Is there any alternative to this query to display monthly attendance report ?

If this query is okay then for those months which have 30 days in it, result for 31 days is displayed. Is there any solution to this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screenshot which explain what type of report I want:

[image]

Comment: i got this solution for u try this 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/display-monthly-attendance-report-in-mysql

Comment: This post is related to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042710/mysql-count-everyday-in-a-month-returns-blob-2b-instead-of-number It may help you

Answer (score 0):

No idea if your original query would work but something like this would be simpler:

```
select DAY(date),count(*) from attendance where MONTH(date) = 2 group by DAY(date);
```

That should get the attendance for February. The output would be:

```
+-----------+----------+
| DAY(date) | count(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|      18   |        1 |
|      19   |        2 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: actually i forgot to specify that 'attStatus' column can contain values 'P', 'A', 'WO', 'M' etc. and i want to show status for each day in my report..

Comment: how do you want to show the status of attStatus per day? There would be one for each attendee and you are grouping attendee stats per day? Would be good if you posted your intended report output in the question

Comment: i have posted an update. i want to use this kind of report.. this query works fine.. but can any alternative short query be used ??

Answer (score 0):

First, create a help table:

```
CREATE TABLE days
( d TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
) ;

INSERT INTO days
VALUES
(0), (1), (2), ..., (31) ;
```

Then you can try this. It will return less columns than your query though:

```
SELECT 
    a.empID
  , GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.attStatus IS NULL
                           THEN 'N'
                           ELSE a.attStatus
                  END
                  ORDER BY dates.dateCheck)
    AS days
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN a.attStatus='P' THEN 1 END )
    AS totalP
FROM
    ( SELECT monthStart + INTERVAL d DAY
             AS dateCheck
      FROM days
        CROSS JOIN
          ( SELECT '2011-07-01' AS monthStart 
          ) AS m 
      WHERE MONTH(monthStart + INTERVAL d DAY) = MONTH(monthStart)
    ) AS dates
  LEFT JOIN attendance AS a
    ON a.`date` = dates.dateCheck
WHERE a.deptID = 1 
GROUP BY a.empID
```