# MySQL count(*) everyday in a month returns [BLOB-2B] instead of number

Tags: mysql, count, blob

I'm going to count every rows each day in a month with a specific user id(vwr_tid). Everything works fine - the result shows up in a table but one thing. A count each days doesn't comes up. It becomes [BLOB-xx] instead of number of rows that day. Here is my code :

```
SELECT MONTH_v, YEAR_V, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=1, views, null)) AS '1',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=2, views, null)) AS '2',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=3, views, null)) AS '3',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=4, views, null)) AS '4',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=5, views, null)) AS '5',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=6, views, null)) AS '6',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=7, views, null)) AS '7',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=8, views, null)) AS '8',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=9, views, null)) AS '9',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=10, views, null)) AS '10',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=11, views, null)) AS '11',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=12, views, null)) AS '12',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=13, views, null)) AS '13',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=14, views, null)) AS '14',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=15, views, null)) AS '15',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=16, views, null)) AS '16',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=17, views, null)) AS '17',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=18, views, null)) AS '18',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=19, views, null)) AS '19',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=20, views, null)) AS '20',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=21, views, null)) AS '21',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=22, views, null)) AS '22',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=23, views, null)) AS '23',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=24, views, null)) AS '24',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=25, views, null)) AS '25',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=26, views, null)) AS '26',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=27, views, null)) AS '27',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=28, views, null)) AS '28',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=29, views, null)) AS '29',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=30, views, null)) AS '30',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=31, views, null)) AS '31'
FROM
(
 SELECT DAY(vwr_date) AS day_v, 
 MONTH(vwr_date) AS MONTH_v, 
 Year(vwr_date) AS YEAR_V,
 date(vwr_date) AS date_v, 
 count(vwr_id) AS views 
 FROM car_viewer 
 WHERE Year(vwr_date)='2012' AND vwr_tid='18' 
 GROUP BY date_v 
) as viewz
GROUP BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V 
ORDER BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V DESC
```

The script is updated from @rs : [Count record each day of a month from mysql into html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017585/count-record-each-day-of-a-month-from-mysql-into-html-table)

The result.
[image: Blob result instead of count]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need for `GROUP_CONCAT()`, when `SUM()` will serve your needs:

```
SELECT MONTH_v, YEAR_V, 
SUM(IF(day_v=1, views, 0)) AS '1',
SUM(IF(day_v=2, views, 0)) AS '2',
SUM(IF(day_v=3, views, 0)) AS '3',
SUM(IF(day_v=4, views, 0)) AS '4',
SUM(IF(day_v=5, views, 0)) AS '5',
SUM(IF(day_v=6, views, 0)) AS '6',
SUM(IF(day_v=7, views, 0)) AS '7',
SUM(IF(day_v=8, views, 0)) AS '8',
SUM(IF(day_v=9, views, 0)) AS '9',
SUM(IF(day_v=10, views, 0)) AS '10',
SUM(IF(day_v=11, views, 0)) AS '11',
SUM(IF(day_v=12, views, 0)) AS '12',
SUM(IF(day_v=13, views, 0)) AS '13',
SUM(IF(day_v=14, views, 0)) AS '14',
SUM(IF(day_v=15, views, 0)) AS '15',
SUM(IF(day_v=16, views, 0)) AS '16',
SUM(IF(day_v=17, views, 0)) AS '17',
SUM(IF(day_v=18, views, 0)) AS '18',
SUM(IF(day_v=19, views, 0)) AS '19',
SUM(IF(day_v=20, views, 0)) AS '20',
SUM(IF(day_v=21, views, 0)) AS '21',
SUM(IF(day_v=22, views, 0)) AS '22',
SUM(IF(day_v=23, views, 0)) AS '23',
SUM(IF(day_v=24, views, 0)) AS '24',
SUM(IF(day_v=25, views, 0)) AS '25',
SUM(IF(day_v=26, views, 0)) AS '26',
SUM(IF(day_v=27, views, 0)) AS '27',
SUM(IF(day_v=28, views, 0)) AS '28',
SUM(IF(day_v=29, views, 0)) AS '29',
SUM(IF(day_v=30, views, 0)) AS '30',
SUM(IF(day_v=31, views, 0)) AS '31'
FROM
(
 SELECT DAY(vwr_date) AS day_v, 
 MONTH(vwr_date) AS MONTH_v, 
 Year(vwr_date) AS YEAR_V,
 date(vwr_date) AS date_v, 
 count(vwr_id) AS views 
 FROM car_viewer 
 WHERE Year(vwr_date)='2012' AND vwr_tid='18' 
 GROUP BY date_v 
) as viewz
GROUP BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V 
ORDER BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V DESC;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75aa8/1 for a working example.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for @Ross Smith II. Very appreciated.

Comment: One more thing @Ross, I'd like to count all records each month as well. I know that it could be done with count(vwr_id) as mon_views but I can't make it without errors. Please suggest.

Comment: Wouldn't `SUM(views) AS mon_views` give you the total views for the month?

Comment: It wouldn't. I've tried to put count(vwr_id) as mon_views after SUM(IF(day_v=31, views, 0)) AS '31' nor count(vwr_id) AS views. Any suggestion?