# Mysql count total viewer each month

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I'm going to count every viewer from a database each month. I tried many ways but I have no luck. Here is the code sample

```
SELECT MONTH_v, YEAR_V, 
SUM(IF(day_v=1, views, 0)) AS '1',
SUM(IF(day_v=2, views, 0)) AS '2',
SUM(IF(day_v=3, views, 0)) AS '3',
SUM(IF(day_v=4, views, 0)) AS '4',
SUM(IF(day_v=5, views, 0)) AS '5',
SUM(IF(day_v=6, views, 0)) AS '6',
SUM(IF(day_v=7, views, 0)) AS '7',
SUM(IF(day_v=8, views, 0)) AS '8',
SUM(IF(day_v=9, views, 0)) AS '9',
SUM(IF(day_v=10, views, 0)) AS '10',
SUM(IF(day_v=11, views, 0)) AS '11',
SUM(IF(day_v=12, views, 0)) AS '12',
SUM(IF(day_v=13, views, 0)) AS '13',
SUM(IF(day_v=14, views, 0)) AS '14',
SUM(IF(day_v=15, views, 0)) AS '15',
SUM(IF(day_v=16, views, 0)) AS '16',
SUM(IF(day_v=17, views, 0)) AS '17',
SUM(IF(day_v=18, views, 0)) AS '18',
SUM(IF(day_v=19, views, 0)) AS '19',
SUM(IF(day_v=20, views, 0)) AS '20',
SUM(IF(day_v=21, views, 0)) AS '21',
SUM(IF(day_v=22, views, 0)) AS '22',
SUM(IF(day_v=23, views, 0)) AS '23',
SUM(IF(day_v=24, views, 0)) AS '24',
SUM(IF(day_v=25, views, 0)) AS '25',
SUM(IF(day_v=26, views, 0)) AS '26',
SUM(IF(day_v=27, views, 0)) AS '27',
SUM(IF(day_v=28, views, 0)) AS '28',
SUM(IF(day_v=29, views, 0)) AS '29',
SUM(IF(day_v=30, views, 0)) AS '30',
SUM(IF(day_v=31, views, 0)) AS '31'
FROM
(
 SELECT DAY(vwr_date) AS day_v, 
 MONTH(vwr_date) AS MONTH_v, 
 Year(vwr_date) AS YEAR_V,
 date(vwr_date) AS date_v, 
 count(vwr_id) AS views 
 FROM car_viewer 
 WHERE Year(vwr_date)='2012' AND vwr_tid='18' 
 GROUP BY date_v 
) as viewz
GROUP BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V 
ORDER BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V DESC;
```

The live view is here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75aa8/1

The question is I'd like to add two columns to the right of each rows:

1. Total = every viewer including 0 of each row.
2. Average = average viewer of each row.

Please don't hesitate to give me a hand. :)

Ref: [MySQL count(*) everyday in a month returns [BLOB-2B] instead of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042710/mysql-count-everyday-in-a-month-returns-blob-2b-instead-of-number/13042896#comment17724127_13042896)

Credit : Ross Smith II

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `SUM(views)` in the outer query:

```
SELECT MONTH_v, YEAR_V, 

  ...

  SUM(IF(day_v=30, views, 0)) AS '30',
  SUM(IF(day_v=31, views, 0)) AS '31',
  SUM(views)
FROM
(
 SELECT DAY(vwr_date) AS day_v,

 ....
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75aa8/10)

Comment: That is? I've tried it many times before. But this time it's work. Many thanks.